# Add an additional table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have to write an essay about another text. Therefore, I have to attach an additional table of contents, which does not actually show my document's structure, but lists sections that are not included in my document.

To clarify: There should be a normal TOC that lists my sections plus another TOC placed anywhere in my own document - not necessarily in the appendix or so.

To make things a little bit more difficult, the "second" TOC should not contain page numbers.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum...

\section{Some text}
    blah blah

\section{Structure}
%Additional TOC defined here

\end{document}
```

It should look like this:

```
Table of Contents
1  Introduction..................................1
2  Some text.....................................2
3  Structure.....................................4


1 Introduction
Lorem ipsum...

2 Some text
blah blah

3 Structure
  1  First Chapter
  2  Second Chapter
      2.1  A Subsection
      2.2  Another Subsection
  3  Last Chapter
```

Thanks for sharing your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the additional "TOC" should use the same settings for the `section` and `subsection` entries:

```
\documentclass[toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}[2018/12/30]% needs version 3.26a
\DeclareNewTOC{str}
\BeforeStartingTOC[str]{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    linefill=\hfill,% no dots
    pagenumberformat=\gobble% no page number
  ]{tocline}{section,subsection}%
}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}

\newcounter{strsection}
\newcounter{strsubsection}
\counterwithin{strsubsection}{strsection}

\newcommand\addstr[2]{%
  \stepcounter{str#1}%
  \addxcontentsline{str}{#1}[\csname thestr#1\endcsname]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum...

\section{Some text}
    blah blah

\section{Structure}
\listoftoc*{str}
\addstr{section}{First Chapter}
\addstr{section}{Second Chapter}
\addstr{subsection}{A Subsection}
\addstr{subsection}{Another Subsection}
\addstr{section}{Last Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Because of a comment below: Overleaf seems to use an older TeX-Distribution, so `\counterwithin` needs package `chnngcntr`. The KOMA-Script Version there is outdated, too: a new project uses version KOMA-Script version 3.23, current version on CTAN is 3.26b. So you can not use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries`. You have to replace it by two `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` commands.

```
\documentclass[toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}[2017/04/13]% tested for version 3.23
\usepackage{chngcntr}% <- needed for older TeX Distributions

\DeclareNewTOC{str}
\BeforeStartingTOC[str]{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    linefill=\hfill,% no dots
    pagenumberformat=\gobble% no page number
  ]{tocline}{section}%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    linefill=\hfill,% no dots
    pagenumberformat=\gobble% no page number
  ]{tocline}{subsection}%
}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}

\newcounter{strsection}
\newcounter{strsubsection}
\counterwithin{strsubsection}{strsection}

\newcommand\addstr[2]{%
  \stepcounter{str#1}%
  \addxcontentsline{str}{#1}[\csname thestr#1\endcsname]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum...

\section{Some text}
    blah blah

\section{Structure}
\listoftoc*{str}
\addstr{section}{First Chapter}
\addstr{section}{Second Chapter}
\addstr{subsection}{A Subsection}
\addstr{subsection}{Another Subsection}
\addstr{section}{Last Chapter}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: This is exactly what I searched for. But when pasting your code to Overleaf, it throws me four errors. After adding `\usepackage{chngcntr}`, there are two left: `Undefined control sequence. l.36 \listoftoc*{str}` and `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. l.1 ... {section}{\numberline {1}First Chapter}{1}`. After commenting out the `DeclareNewTOC` block, all errors are gone, but the additional TOC has page numbers.

Comment: Overleaf uses an older TeX Distribution and an outdated KOMA-Script version. You have to replace `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries` by two `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` commands: one for `strsection` and one for `strsubsection`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use lists.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

{
    \setlist[enumerate]{label*=.\arabic*}
    \setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\arabic*}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First Chapter
        \item Second Chapter
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item A Section
            \item Another Section
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item A Subsection
                \item One More Subsection
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Last Chapter
    \end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

You can easily configure the appearance of the lists using `enumitem` and keep the design local by enclosing everything in a group.