# Additional table of contents within document

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I have to write an Exposé which needs to contain a second table of contents within a section in the document. The requirements are basically the same as already discussed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494865/add-an-additional-table-of-contents), with the difference, that i not only need `\section` and `\subsection` but also `\subsubsection`.

Edit: It seems that my question was not detailed enough, because it was closed as it was already answered elsewhere. The linked question was about the same TOC multiple times. I do need a separate TOC with individual headings not connected to the current document. The TOC needs to be the TOC of a future document, so it must not refer to any regular headings of the current one.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum...

\section{Some text}
    blah blah

\section{Structure}
%TOC of future document without page numbers, not referring to other current headings.

\section{Discussion}
Some Text

\end{document}
```

Should look like this:

```
Table of Contents
1  Introduction..................................1
2  Some text.....................................2
3  Structure.....................................4
4  Discussion....................................6


1 Introduction
Lorem ipsum...

2 Some text
blah blah

3 Structure
%TOC of future document without page numbers
  1  First Chapter
  2  Second Chapter
      2.1  A Subsection
      2.2  Another Subsection
          2.2.1 A Subsubsection
          2.2.1 Another Subsubsection
  3  Last Chapter
4 Discussion
Some Text
```

I was basically able to implement the proposed [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494882/234143) and have also tried to add a `\subsubsection` by myself but was not able to.

The other proposed solutions using `enumitem` has a different styling then my normal TOC. Would prefer to have the additional TOC in the same styling as my main TOC for the document.

[image: Current Document without subsubsection and enumitem with wrong styling]

Do you have any tips how to add a third layer to the KOMA-Script solution?
Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: This seems to be less about "having a TOC repeated", and more about "creating a fake TOC" (with subsubsections).  Is that correct?  Do you have the other document to use its toc file, or are you needing to create the fake toc from nothing?

Comment: Yes, it's like a "fake TOC". The future document is not existing yet. So it would be a fake toc from nothing. An Exposè is a planning document for a future document in this case my Bachelor Thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include `subsubsection` in the structure section of [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494882/234143), add `subsubsection` to the last argument of `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries`

```
latex
\BeforeStartingTOC[str]{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    linefill=\hfill,%
    pagenumberformat=\gobble%
  ]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection}% <=== subsubsection added
}
```

and define the new counter `strsubsubsection`

```latex
\newcounter{strsubsubsection}
\counterwithin{strsubsubsection}{strsubsection}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC{str}
\BeforeStartingTOC[str]{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    linefill=\hfill,%
    pagenumberformat=\gobble%
  ]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection}% <=== subsubsection added
}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}

\newcounter{strsection}
\newcounter{strsubsection}
\counterwithin{strsubsection}{strsection}
\newcounter{strsubsubsection}% <=== added
\counterwithin{strsubsubsection}{strsubsection}% <=== added

\newcommand\addstr[2]{%
  \stepcounter{str#1}%
  \addxcontentsline{str}{#1}[\csname thestr#1\endcsname]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum...

\section{Some text}
    blah blah

\section{Structure}
\listoftoc*{str}
\addstr{section}{First Section}
\addstr{section}{Second Section}
\addstr{subsection}{A Subsection}
\addstr{subsection}{Another Subsection}
\addstr{subsubsection}{A Subsubsection}% <=== added
\addstr{subsubsection}{Another Subsubsection}% <=== added
\addstr{section}{Last Section}

\section{Discussion}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But if you want to use a class with chapters (ie. `scrreprt` or `scrbook`) then you have to add the chapter level to the structure chapter:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\DeclareNewTOC{str}
\BeforeStartingTOC[str]{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    linefill=\hfill,% no dots
    pagenumberformat=\gobble% no page number
  ]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection}% <=== chapter added
}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}

\newcounter{strchapter}% <=== added
\newcounter{strsection}
\counterwithin{strsection}{strchapter}% <=== changed
\newcounter{strsubsection}
\counterwithin{strsubsection}{strsection}

\newcommand\addstr[2]{%
  \stepcounter{str#1}%
  \addxcontentsline{str}{#1}[\csname thestr#1\endcsname]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Some text}
    blah blah

\chapter{Structure}
\listoftoc*{str}
\addstr{chapter}{First Chapter}
\addstr{chapter}{Second Chapter}
\addstr{section}{A Section}
\addstr{section}{Another Section}
\addstr{subsection}{A Subsection}% <=== added
\addstr{subsection}{Another Subsection}% <=== added
\addstr{section}{Last Chapter}

\chapter{Last Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For my document it's somehow not working. It's not adding the `subsubsections` and just stays like shown in my initial screenshot. I have tried your solution in a new blank file. There everything seems fine. I am using a template from my university, so I guess there might be something interfering with it. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: Issue was caused by `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` somewhere else in the template. Changed it and now your solution is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general solution for having multiple ToCs, LoFs etc. It is not specific to the `scrartcl` class. Note it involves redefining a kernel macro.

```
% tocsprob.tex  SE 581163

\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

% Modify a kernel macro so that ToC, etc files only closed at the document end
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@starttoc}[1]{%
  \begingroup\makeatletter
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \AtEndDocument{%
        \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
        \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
      }%
    \fi
  \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum...

\section{Some text}
    blah blah
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph} Text

\section{Structure}
Additional TOC defined here
% have ToC include \paragraph s
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}} 
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

By default `\subsubsection` s are included in the ToC. I have shown how to include `\paragraph` s in the second ToC in case you ever need that.

(The `memoir` class allows multiple ToC, etc., by default.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If i understand it correctly, the second TOC is also referring to the existing headings of the document. Maybe i havent explained it well enough, sorry. The second TOC i need, will be the TOC of a future document, so must not contain existing headings, but will be a new one.

Comment: @KiQuz So that is a completely different question. I answered your oroginal question, basically "How can I have multiple ToCs in my document?" to "How can I have the current ToC in my document plus a ToC from a document yet to be processed?"

Comment: Yes, sorry. English is not my mother tongue, but i tried my best to explain it as detailed as possible. I will clean up my question later on to have a better documentation for everyone.